# The matrix norm $||A||=\max_{\langle u|u\rangle=1}|\langle u|A|u\rangle|$ in the proof of Lieb's theorem

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, linear-algebra, trace-norm

> In [Exercise A6.4, Appendix 6: Proof of Lieb’s theorem, Page 645, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), A matrix norm of $A$ is defined as $$||A||=\max_{\langle u|u\rangle=1}|\langle u|A|u\rangle|=\max_{u^Tu=1}|u^TAu|$$
> If $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and defining $\lambda$ to be the maximum of the set $|\lambda_i|$ then
>
> 1. $||A||\ge \lambda$
> 2. When $A$ is hermitian, $||A||=\lambda$
> 3. When $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}$, $||A||=3/2>1=\lambda$

---

For any fixed symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, fixed rectangular matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and fixed vector $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we can define
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}a^Tu=a\quad &\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial u}|u|^2=2x\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u^TAu)=2Au\quad &\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial u}|Bx|^2=2B^TBu\\
\end{align}
We need to find the critical points of the function $u^TAu$ subject to the constraint $|u|^2=u^Tu=1$.

ie., to find the critical points of the Lagrangian function, $L(u,\lambda)=u^TAu-\lambda(u^Tu-1)$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u^TAu)-\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial u}|u|^2\\
&=2Au-\lambda(2u)=0\\
\implies Au&=\lambda u\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\lambda}&=|u|^2-1=0\implies |u|^2=1
\end{align}
Therefore, $u,\lambda$ must be an eigenpair of $A$.

$\therefore$ the eigenvectors of $A$ are the critical points of $u^TAu$

$\therefore$ $\max_{u^Tu=1}u^TAu=\lambda_\max$, the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A$.

So it looks like,
$||A||=\max_{\langle u|u\rangle=1}|\langle u|A|u\rangle|=\max_{u^Tu=1}|u^TAu|$ is the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A$.

---

**My Doubt**

If we take $u$ to be the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the matrix $A$ then $\langle u|A|u\rangle=\lambda\langle u|u\rangle=\lambda$. And this implies $||A||=\max_{\langle u|u\rangle=1}|\langle u|A|u\rangle|\ge \lambda$, fine.

But, given that the proof above shows the critical values of $\langle u|A|u\rangle$ occur at the unit eigenvectors, how is it possible that we can have $||A||>\lambda$?

For example, considering the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}$ which only has $1$ as its eigenvalue with eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$ is said to have the norm $||A||=\max_{\langle u|u\rangle=1}|\langle u|A|u\rangle|=3/2$ which obviously not occur at any eigenvector of $A$.

---

[Crossposted on math.stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657366/the-norm-a-max-langle-uu-rangle-1-langle-uau-rangle-for-nondiagon)

Comment: seems to have been already answered on math.SE. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $\langle u,Au\rangle=\lambda$ with $u$ eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$. Thus obviously maximising this quantity over all unit vectors $u$ gives you something larger than $\lambda$. Same goes putting absolute values on both sides (note that the statement should be $\|A\|\ge|\lambda|$, unless you're ensured $\lambda\in\mathbb R$)

Comment: @glS I am confused particularly about the possibility that the maximum of $|\langle u,Au\rangle|$ occurs for some unit vector $u$ which is not an eigenvector of $A$, when $A$ is nondiagonalizable such as the example $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$, yet the proof shows the critical values of $\langle u,Au\rangle$ occurs at the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: @glS The proof seems to show that the critical values of $\langle u,Au\rangle$ occurs at the eigenvectors. Then why do we have $||A||=3/2$ for the given matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$?How do I justify this ?

Comment: I don't understand the need to mention critical values. $\lambda=\langle u,Au\rangle$ regardless of whether $A$ is diagonalisable are not, and you don't need to discuss critical values or maximisations for it. It's just because the definition of eigenvalue means $Au=\lambda u$

Comment: @glS My doubt is, given the proof shows the critical values occur at the eigenvectors, how do I justify the case when $||A||>\lambda$, which corresponds to $u$ which is not an eigenvector, as is the case of $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.